# How to create pages dynamically using tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, oop, matplotlib, tkinter

As per user input I would like to create pages on tkinter. Number of pages vary accordingly.

I'm able to achieve the same using predefined number of pages by using classes. (Source: https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/)

Is it possible by calling a function that creates a page repeatedly as per input?
For example, if user enters 3 then 3 pages should be created, if 4 then 4 must be created etc.(Each page is different but I'll get to that later.)

I'm working with Python 2.7.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It _is_ possible. Perhaps paste the sample [mcve] and how exactly you failed so that this is a _question_ as opposed to an order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ttk.Notebook. This is for python 3. For python 2.7 I think you need to replace `tkinter` with `Tkinter` with a capital T. Also I think `raw_input` instead of `input`. And ttk is it's own package so `import ttk` instead of `from tkinter import ttk`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

num_pages = input("Number of pages? ")

root = tk.Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs = []

for n in range(0, int(num_pages)):
    tabs.append(ttk.Frame(note))
    note.add(tabs[n], text = "Tab {}".format(n))

note.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I wasn't aware of the notebook widget so this was very helpful :) I will now try and get to work on customizing the same! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271587/how-to-create-pages-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment85577841_49271587)